# Display an updated WritableBitmap in c# Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have the following code that reads an image and alters the pixels to convert to greyscale and then sets it as the source for display.  The problem is that it always displays the unaltered image, even though I have verified the pixel byte array is changed.

```
using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream imageDataStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{

    int _width = Convert.ToInt32((int)imgDisplay.Width);
    int _height = Convert.ToInt32((int)imgDisplay.Width);

    originalBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(_width, _height);
    imageDataStream.Seek(0);
    await originalBitmap.SetSourceAsync(imageDataStream);

    srcPixelStream = originalBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] originalPixels = new byte[4 * _width * _height];
    int pixelLength = srcPixelStream.Read(originalPixels, 0, 4 * _width * _height);

    byte[] ResultPixels = EdgeDetection.GreyIt(originalPixels);
    srcPixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    srcPixelStream.Write(ResultPixels, 0, pixelLength);
    originalBitmap.Invalidate();

    imgDisplay.Source = originalBitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the most obvious omission in your code is that you don't dispose/close the `srcPixelStream` object.

I suppose it's also possible that `pixelLength` is being set to some value smaller than you expect; note that in general read operations on streams are *not* required to return all of the bytes you asked for it to read, even if the full number of bytes are theoretically available. That's why read methods return the count of bytes actually read. You may need to read multiple times until you get as many bytes as you want.

Lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure what's wrong. But I would start by adding a `using` statement to the initialization of `srcPixelStream` (and preferably, move the declaration of the variable to the `using` statement itself).